# Mafia-style modern vampire fantasy TV show

Tags: story-identification, tv, vampire

Some years ago I watched a TV series about a Mafia-style contemporary vampire family.

It was American (or possibly Canadian) and centred on a man who had separated himself from the family but returned to become a sort of consigliere.

There may have been slight black humour but I'm sure it wasn't a comedy. I remember some Dracula-type wall climbing and romance.

It was shown late at night on UK television in the 80s or 90s. I enjoyed it very much but I think it only had a very short run and possibly had been canceled early.

Additional: I seem to remember the MC being a smooth, Italian-looking guy, perhaps. Also the vampire bit was rather subtext, at least to begin with. Not much vampire lore and single family oriented.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_vampire_television_series

Comment: Unfortunately I found nothing like the show I mean in the Wikipedia list.

Comment: This made me remember [Vampiros en la Habana](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090249/), with mafia style wars between vampire families. But it does not match the other criteria: it was an animation film and it was made in Cuba, I am not sure if it was ever dubbed.

Answer (score 6):

[*Kindred: The Embraced*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115232/) had a very mafia vibe to it.  It first aired in 1996.  It had romance, Nosferatu style vampires, and human looking ones.  It was set in contemporary San Francisco.  Although there were a lot of differences from the tabletop game, the show was explicitly a tie-in with the "*Vampire: The Masquerade*" franchise.

Comment: I've had a look at this and it doesn't look like what I remember.